# Horizontal website / single row table

Tags: jquery, css, html, infinite

I am currently making a site to house my art-portfolio. For my portfolio page I am using a table with a single row  and would like it to have an infinite amount of column sections in that single row. Unfortunately I am only getting 4 photos in the row and the 5th automatically gets pushed below as if it is trying to start a new row. I am not quite sure how to fix this. I don't have a set amount of photos to put into the table, I will be adding more and more, so there could be no real limit to the amount of imgs I would like to insert into the table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Stephen K.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please copy your HTML and paste it into your question for us to review?

Comment: @EthanPelton Good response. Normally the response to a question like this is pure nerd rage lol

Comment: What you are describing shouldn't' be possible. If you have a single row with an infinite number of columns in the row, one image per column, it should never wrap, unless of course you override the default css of table cells/rows.

Answer (score 1):

in the css

```
ul.infinte{
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: auto;
}
ul.infinte li{
display: inline-block;
}
```

in the html

```
<ul class="infinite">
<li><img src="image1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image4.jpg" /></li>
...
<li><img src="image999.jpg" /></li>
<ul>
```

This should keep your images in one row. Don't need to use table, instead use ul>li, it's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something more complex than just merely  tags to continually accept and add photos to a table row. Although it would be possible to build a table with the  tags being created dynamically depending on how many photos you have, you would quickly learn that this is not a scalable solution :D.

Perhaps having an image server would be best.